# Mocha Runner Finishes Process Before Promises Resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, mocha.js

I'm writing a mocha test reporter to dump test results into elasticsearch. Mocha emits events for `suite`, `pass`, `fail` and others that can be subscribed to.

When an event is emitted, I issue a promise using `elasticsearch.js` to create the document in elasticsearch. I've wrapped that up like so...

```
function addResult(result)
{
  return client.create({
    index: index_name,
    type: document_type,
    body: result
  });
}
```

If the suite bails out early and doesn't run the remaining tests, Mocha doesn't emit a `defered` event for the remaining tests. My solution is to create an array of tests on the `suite` event and remove them as they finish. If any are remaining on the `suite end` event, I issue promises for these to be added to elasticsearch as `bailouts`.

```
  runner.on('suite end', function (done)
  {
    /*
     * If the suite bailed out early and didn't run some of it's tests,
     * we want to make sure we track them as skipped.
     */
    if (remainingTests.length != 0)
    {
      console.log('       Suite ended with ' + remainingTests.length + ' tests remaining');

      remainingTests.forEach(function (skipped_test) {

        elastic.addResult(skipped_test)
          .then(function (response) {
            if (response.created) { console.log('       Result added to ES') }
            else { console.error("Error adding to ES: " + response); }
          })
          .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
          });

      }); // end forEach
    } // end if

  }); // end...suite end
```

The problem is that the process ends without fulfilling all of the promises for the `bailouts` and I cannot find a way to force it to wait.

I've tried creating an array of all the promises and calling

```
Promises.all()
```

with no luck.

I've also tried `setTimeout` with no luck.

Comment: You're approaching this wrong. Mocha shouldn't bail out on tests if they contain Promises. Either it waits for the Promise to resolve/reject and marks the test accordingly, or it gives up on the Promise resolution, and marks the test as failing. Anything else should not be acceptable.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you. Mocha issues a runner when a suite begins, which contains the tests. Then, it also issues a runner for each test when the test begins that contains emitters for passes, fails, is pending, or ending. If the suite hits a bail out condition (timeout or fails a "step"-ed test), Mocha considers the remaining tests "deferred" and never issues runners or events for them. It actually discards them to prevent a memory leak.

Comment: The Promises I'm issuing are for sending the result to a database.